# What can I use to get just one set of text from divs with the same class using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, attributes

I have question that I feel should be simple but I am having issues getting the result I need. I can not change the HTML. Any help would be great!

I have a set up like this.

```
<div class="container">
    <a href="doesn'tmatter" class="myAtag"></a>
    <div class='mydiv'>this is text1</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <a href="doesn'tmatter"></a>
    <div class='mydiv'>this is text2</div>
</div>
```

I am trying to get the text from each of those divs, set it to a var that I can then use to add a data attribute to the  above it.

```
var DivText = $('mydiv').text();
$('.myAtag').attr('data', 'DivTest');
```

The problem I run into this that the data attribute is then filled with the text from both divs.

```
<div class="container">
    <a href="doesn'tmatter" class="myAtag" data="this is text1 this this text2"></a>
    <div class='mydiv'>this is text1</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <a href="doesn'tmatter" class="myAtag" data="this is text1 this this text2"></a>
    <div class='mydiv'>this is text2</div>
</div>
```

What can I use/how can I modifiy my jquery to achieve this outcome?

```
<div class="container">
    <a href="doesn'tmatter" class="myAtag" data="this is text1"></a>
    <div class='mydiv'>this is text1</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <a href="doesn'tmatter" class="myAtag" data="this this text2"></a>
    <div class='mydiv'>this is text2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a callback to set each data attribute differently

```
$('.myAtag').attr('data-text', function() {
    return $(this).next('.mydiv').text();
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/5FQ7v/)

It's usually a good idea to use a key, as in `data-whatever`
You could also use `data()`, but that sets the data internally in jQuery and does **not** add an attribute